# what will be the dp and transitions in this problem

Tags: dynamic-programming

Vasya has a string s of length n consisting only of digits 0 and 1. Also he has an array a of length n.

Vasya performs the following operation until the string becomes empty: choose some consecutive substring of equal characters, erase it from the string and glue together the remaining parts (any of them can be empty). For example, if he erases substring 111 from string 1**111**10 he will get the string 110. Vasya gets ax points for erasing substring of length x.

Vasya wants to maximize his total points, so help him with this!

https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1107/E

**i was trying to get my head around the editorial,but couldn't understand it... can anyone tell an easy way to do it?**

**input:**

7

1101001

3 4 9 100 1 2 3

**output:**

109

**Explanation**

the optimal sequence of erasings is: 11**0**1001 → 1110**0**1 → 111**0**1 → **1111** → ∅.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we consider removing prefixes instead of substrings. Why?

We try to remove a consecutive prefix of a particular state which is actually a substring in the main string. So, our DP states will be **start index, end index, prefix length**.

Let's consider an example **str = "1010110"**. Here, initially start=0, end=7, and prefix=1(the first '1' will be the only prefix now). we iterate over all the indices in the current state except the starting index and check if **str[i]==str[start]**. Here, for example, **str[4]==str[0]**. Now we divide the string into **"010"** with prefix=1(**0**10) && **"110"** with prefix=2(**1**010**1**10). These two are now two individual subproblems. So, when there remains a string with length **1**, we return **a<sub>prefix</sub>**.

Here is my [code](https://codeforces.com/contest/1107/submission/49063233).